# JWT not included in payload for Custom Activity endpoints

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We're creating a Journey Builder Custom Activity. [The documentation](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/workflow-format/activity-formats/rest.html) explains:

> If the "useJwt" property is set to true below for any of the REST Activity's methods, then a JWT for the account is generated, encoded and sent in as the "jwt" property in the POST Body.

We've tried this, but we don't receive the JWT payload in the body. Is this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same results and have notified the engineers.

**Update**: this has been assigned and an engineer is working on it.

Comment: Hi Drew, do you have an update on this? I note that it's still not working.

Comment: This has been slated for the 05 release which is July 31.

Comment: Anyone got any news on this 11/2020 and I am experiencing the same issue